# inner join is taking forever

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to update one variable on a table with ~1m rows in mysql with an update statement with the following  code, however, it is taking over 10hrs to run which is just odd! Is there a more efficient or better way to do it? This is mysql code:

```
UPDATE test.ratings as a 
INNER JOIN test.fgform as b ON a.race_id = b.race_id 
SET a.FGspeed = b.FG;
```

Comment: do you have `race_id` index for both tables?

Comment: does that happen on a local machine or on a remote server?

Comment: Whenever you're troubleshooting performance issues like this, you should generate an explain plan (or query execution plan) for the query and identify where the highest costs are.  Most likely adding indexes can help fix the problem.  Also, if this is a development machine with a slow, fragmented hard drive, with fragmented files, it can hurt performance alot.

Comment: Thanks - indexing seems to solve the problem completly.